# Get index of nested DIVs in jquery for removing html element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the nested DIVs in HTML Code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                         <div class="table" id="preference">
                            <div class="tr">
                                <div class="td"><p>Category : </p></div>
                                <div class="td">
                                    <?php $js = 'id="selCat"'; ?>
                                    <?php echo form_dropdown('selCat',$subcats,'0', 'selCat');?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="td"><p>Sub Category : </p></div>
                                <div class="td">
                                    <select id="selSubCat" name="selSubCat">
                                        <option value="0" selected="true">-Select a category first-</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="td"><p>Score : </p></div>
                                <div class="td">
                                    <input type="text" size="1"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="tr">
                                <a href="#" id="btn_Add">Add more [+]</a>
                         </div>
                    </form>
```

So whenever the add more button is clicked, jquery function will be called and add a new a element to the  with id = "preference"

Here is the jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
        var fileId = 0;
        var wrapper = $("#preference");
        var add_button = $("#btn_Add");
        var x = 1;

     $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="tr">' 
            +   '<div class="td">Category :</div>'
            +   '<div class="td">'
                +   '<select>'
                        + '<option>1 </option> '
                +   '</select>' 
            +   '</div>'
            +   '<div class="td">Sub Category :</div>'
            +   '<div class="td"> </div>'
            +   '<div class="td">Score :</div>'
            +   '<div class="td"><input type="text" size="1" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="btnRemove">Remove&nbsp;[-]</a></div>'
            +
            '</div>'
            );
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click","#btnRemove", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).closest("#tr").index();
        alert(index);
        //$(this).parent('#preference').remove(); 
        x--;

     });

      $('#selCat').change(function(){
       var id = $(this).val(); // selected name from dropdown #table
       $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/client/ajax_subcat',  // or "resources/ajax_call" - url to fetch the next dropdown
        async: false,
        type: "POST",     // post
        data: {id:id},  // variable send
        dataType: "html",    // return type
        success: function(data) {  // callback function
         $('#selSubCat').html(data);
        }
       })
      });
     });
    </script>
```

The result of the add button is shown in the picture below

[image]
What I would like to do is, whenver the remove button (link) is clicked it will remove all the element belongs to that particular row.

How can I achieve it ?
I know I need to get the index of the clicked row and remove the elements corresponding to that row.
How can I get the index in the nested div like what I have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close when you tried to use `.closest()`, but you accidentally tried to get an element with the id `TR`, instead of getting the class `TR`. Also, you don't need the index; just remove the `TR` directly.

```
$(this).closest('.tr').remove();
```

Also, don't forget, IDs are designed to be **unique**. If you need to use an ID more than once, you need to use a class, not an ID. `btnRemove` should be a class, not an ID.

Comment: even the index() function returns -1. It is not working. I don't think I can use closest("tr") since I don't wrap the elements using <table> but <div> and the <div class="tr"> which indicates the row does not have any id

Comment: Sorry..your answer works! I mistyped it..I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `class` with name **`tr`** on `div` and you are referring it with `id` i.e. `#` on remove click and hence you were getting index as `-1`. Refer it with class name instead like one below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9v7ocoka/2/)**

```
$(wrapper).on("click","#btnRemove", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var index=$(this).closest('.tr').index();
     alert(index);
     $(this).closest(".tr").remove(); //remove it directly
     x--;
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Now I know my mistake

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using class so slector should be `.tr`

```
var index = $('form .tr').index($(this).closest(".tr"));
alert(index);
```

If you just want to remove it, then

```
$(this).closest(".tr").remove();
```